# Throw Exception through multiple services

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have a little microservice architecture with 3 depending services. Each service represents a seperate Spring Boot project. If an exception occurs on the lowest level of the architecture I would like to throw it through all other services up to the highest/user endpoint service.

Each service API returns a **HttpEntity(Response Entity)** including a specific object. I found a lot of possible solutions like **ResponseEntityExceptionHandlers** but all examples shown for a single service architecture without multiple depending services.

Are there any best practices how to throw an Exception through multiple services with Spring Boot?

Comment: How your services communicate?

Comment: Via rest like post/get

Comment: So A calls B, B calls C and C throw an exception, right?

Comment: Correct. The exeptions contains  specific Information which I would like to proceed in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have three services A (relates directly on B), b (relates directly on C) and C and user calls your service A, but it can be applied to any number of services.

I will briefly describe you the approach

If error occurs in the service C (exception thrown), your code should catch Exception and return a meaningful response. Simplest I can think of would be a `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

      @ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
      public ResponseEntity<ApiErrorDto> handleYourException(YourException e) {
      return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) //or any other suitable 
            .body(new ApiError(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

`ApiError` could be just a basic POJO class with a single field holding the message, or any other field meaningful for your exception handling.

Now when your service B receives response it should check whether it is expected status code or an error status code and act accordingly.

Your `ApiError` class should be shared between all services so that it can be easily serialized/deserialized everywhere. That way once you receive error you can decide what to do next, one of the scenarios could be throwing another exception to be caught by ExceptionHandler in service B.

It's a starter, you can decide whether you want to return a string message in your `ApiError`, or maybe some kind of a meaningful code etc. Bottom line is that you should include that information in the response of the service where error occurs and interpret that information in the calling service.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did exactly the same. My pain point is at receiving and validating the response: final User user = new RestTemplate().postForObject("url", request, User.class);
A User Class is expected and it failes when a  exception returns.

Comment: With status 4xx postForObject should return `HttpClientErrorException` you could catch. Also you can set a `ResponseErrorHandler` for `RestTemplate`

Comment: But then I lose my specific/own exception message I throwed :(

Comment: `HttpClientErrorException` contains response body.

Comment: I was able to extract the exception from the response body with an object mapper. thanks.